# mvc4 web api 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

can anyone see anything wrong with my route configuation? I'm trying to call my web api controller via:

```
localhost/Attribution/api/Client

localhost/Attribution/api/Fund
```

I have a couple of controllers that extend ApiController called ClientController and FundController.

Here is my route configuration. I always get HTTP 404 `The resource cannot be found`.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);


GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "test",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
        defaults: new
    {
            id = RouteParameter.Optional,
                action = RouteParameter.Optional
    });
```

Comment: I've been struggling with the same issue in a WebApi project. Ever figure out what you were doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include an action and that action should be in your controller.  As written, the url /api/Client doesn't know what action to call.  Instead, try:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "test",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new
    {
            action = "Index",
            id = RouteParameter.Optional
    });
```

Then the URL /api/Client should call action "Index" in controller "Client".

Comment: For an ApiController, the actions are all verbs from the httpRequest. So api/Controller/Get would map to an HTTP Get request, api/Controller/Post would map to an HTTP Post request, etc...